# Trying to read AIFF Files Unexpected Error to do with pointer location etc

Tags: c++, pointers, audio, exc-bad-access, aiff

I've been trying to read an AIFF File into a number of variables and I have encountered a problem when trying to read the data part of the data chunk. I get the error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeee1bbce8). I know this usually means theres a problem with the pointer however I have checked and run so many tests and the pointer is not hitting the end of the file so its not that. Please could someone have a look I've tried to make a very simplified version to show the problem I'm getting.

```
int main()
{
    FILE * AIFF;
    int32_t Datasize = 27539504;
    int16_t Data[(Datasize - 8)/2];

    AIFF = fopen("/Volumes/Audio CD/Audio Track.aiff", "r");

    fread(Data, 2, (Datasize - 8)/2, AIFF);

    return 0;
}
```

The error comes up on the fopen line. Also this is in C++ in Xcode on a 64bit Mac.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't appear to check to see if `fopen()` returns NULL... so if `fopen()` fails for whatever reason (most likely because the specified file doesn't exist or can't be opened for reading), then your program will crash when `fread()` tries to dereference the NULL pointer.

Side note:  since .AIFF files are binary files, not ASCII, you should be passing "rb" as the second argument to `fopen()` rather than "r".

Comment: I removed the check to see if NULL just to make the code a lot simpler. Just tried rb but still getting the thread error.

Comment: Okay, then the next likely problem is that most threads' stacks aren't big enough to hold 27MB of data.  Perhaps you are inducing a stack overflow, which is causing the crash?  Try allocating your `Data` array on the heap, instead.  Also, C++ doesn't officially support variable-length arrays, so in order to be standards-compliant you should declare `Datasize` to be `const`.

Comment: Oh ok thanks very much. Could you explain how to allocate it on the heap? The problem is the array length needs to be variable because its dependant on the size of the file its reading.

Comment: `int16_t * Data = new int16_t[(Datasize - 8)/2]; [.... use Data array here....];  delete [] Data;`

Comment: Yes great that worked thank you so much. Its only reading -1 and 0 but I'll work that out. I've never used the delete [] before is that very important?

Comment: If you don't `delete []` the array when you're done using it, the memory will be leaked (i.e. it will be unavailable to the computer until your program exits).  Whether or not that becomes a real problem for you depends on how much RAM your computer has, how long your program runs for, and how much memory you leak.

Comment: Great thanks, I'm guessing there's no ideas as to why its only returning -1 or 0 for every value?